# How to cache the page and adjust the timing to call API

Tags: php, symfony

I am making the application which gets item data from Amazon by product advertisement API.

on Symfony2

1
Normally everytime you access page,it calls amazon API everytime.

However,I dont want to call API manytimes,
I would like to cache the page and call API only sometimes (ex. One time in a day).

I think I can integrate this feature by putting item data in database though,
I think it is a bit lengthy.

It it possible to cache whole page and adjust the timing to call API ?

example my source cord.

```
public function indexAction(){
    $feed = callingAPIandXMLparse("http://www.amazon.co.jp/api?key=12345");
    return $this->render('AcmeTopBundle:Default:index.html.twig', array('feed' => $feed));
}
```

it calls callingAPIandXMLParse() everytime and make html.

I would like to store whole page in cache and not to read API everytime.